# This is related to SQLDiag on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to get the help file for SQLDiag and to my surprise instead of showing the help the utility was executed. SQLCMD which is in the same tools folder did display the help. How do I get to display the help.

More details on my blog:
http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2014/08/sqldiag-on-windows-81-professional.html